# How to use 'ORDER BY' statement in a 'SELECT DISTINCT CASE WHEN' statement in sql & php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, chat

I am trying to create a chat application and am currently listing the conversations that the current user had. 
 This is my SQL Table: (Here 29 is the current user)

```
ID   |  FROM_USER  |  TO_USER  |  MESSAGE      
------------------------------------------------------------
1    |  16         |  29       |  Hey!         
2    |  29         |  18       | Hii..         
3    |  29         |  16       | What's up?
4    |  18         |  29       | Long time no see..
```

What I am trying to do is group the conversations in a descending order like:

```
18: Long time no see...
29 (to 16) : What's up?
```

The php code that I am currently using is as follow:

```
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT DISTINCT CASE WHEN from_user = 29 THEN to_user ELSE from_user END as other_user FROM mytable WHERE from_user = 29 OR to_user = 29 ORDER BY id DESC");
while($fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
$user = $fetch['other_user'];
echo $user.'<br/>';
}
```

But this doesn't seems to work. What am I doing wrong? 
And thanks in advance!

Comment: what is the result now

Comment: To just get the conversation with user 29, wouldn't `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE from_user = 29 OR to_user = 29 ORDER BY id DESC` be what you are after?

Comment: Can you include the full 4-record expected output?

Comment: The result sometimes come as expected. other times it comes the other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CASE WHEN from_user = 29 THEN to_user ELSE from_user END as other_user
FROM mytable
WHERE from_user = 29 OR to_user = 29
ORDER BY id DESC;
```

The column `id` is not defined, because it is not in the `distinct`.  I'm guessing that you do not want it there because the `SELECT DISTINCT` would then return duplicate `other_user`s.

I would recommend aggregation instead of `DISTINCT`.  MySQL makes this easy because you can use column aliases in the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN from_user = 29 THEN to_user ELSE from_user END) as other_user
FROM mytable
WHERE 29 IN (from_user, to_user)
GROUP BY other_user
ORDER BY MAX(id) DESC;
```

This will return the other users in recency order (or at least recency based on the `id` column).

Comment: @MuhammedRanshidAsif . . . There was a cut-and-paste error which I fixed.